# Stop a user from navigating past a signin form via the url

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a website which contains a sign in page which should only allow the people knowing the info to pass the page, but if I type `/nextpage.html` in the url, it takes me past the sign in page. How can I prevent this? (I use javascript, not php)

Comment: Authenticate via the *backend* before sending data back to the client.

Comment: Use a server-side language (PHP) and pass it like that

Comment: Make it `nextpage.php` and do an authentication check in PHP to determine whether the user is allowed to see the page.

Comment: I dont use PHP.

Comment: Where is your user data stored and how do you check if the user data is valid?

Comment: My bad, I misread that. Well, you'll need *some* server-side language, like PHP, to deal with this. Or you use HTTP authentication and let the webserver handle it.

Comment: @jacobdo, It's stored in a sql database, and I use AJAX to connect to an ASP.NET API which returns needed information.

Comment: A client will always be able to see your content if you ask them to authenticate themselves (eg. using a client-side scripting language for authentication).

Comment: Well then make an authentication check server-side in ASP.NET.

Comment: Big-picture-wise: don't even think about browsers or Javascript. It boils down to: can I make an *HTTP request* to your server and your server will divulge "secret" information? Then it's a server-side problem and you need server-side checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of trying different methods, I came across javascript session- and localstorage. This is what helped me since variables stored in them can be used across multiple .js files.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just take care because session (cookies) and localstorage can be manipulated by the user

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.net backend for authentication. Then you do the following:

1. Upon successful sign in you have to set some session variable in
   ASP.net
2. Then on every page load you need to make an ajax call to
   check if the session variable is set, if it is, you show the content
   that you wish to show to an authenticated user, otherwise, show them
   a log in form.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a variable which holds a user login status in session. if user is not logged in make it false or 0 after login make it 0 or true and put in session and check it always before page loads. and destroy session and make it false or 0 on logout.

Comment: I tried this, with exporting and importing a boolean, but ES6 gives tons of errors with that, since it's not yet fully supported.

Comment: so you can use integer value